# Iterate through list of dictionaries with conditions

Tags: python, json, list, loops, dictionary

Assume this where test is a large list of dictionaries(this is just a sample):

```
  test = [
{'alignedWord': 'welcome',
  'case': 'success',
  'end': 0.9400000000000001,
  'start': 0.56
  'word': 'Welcome'},

 {'alignedWord': 'to',
  'case': 'success',
  'end': 1.01,
  'start': 0.94,
  'word': 'to'},

 {'alignedWord': 'story',
  'case': 'not-found-in-audio',
  'word': 'Story'},

 {'alignedWord': 'in',
  'case': 'success',
  'end': 1.4100000000000001,
  'start': 1.34,
  'word': 'in'},

 {'alignedWord': 'a',
  'case': 'success',
  'end': 1.44,
  'start': 1.41,
  'word': 'a'},

 {'alignedWord': 'bottle',
  'case': 'success',
  'end': 1.78,
  'start': 1.44,
  'word': 'Bottle'} ]
```

Output as a json file of each consecutive chunk of `case =='success' and duration_s < 10 :

```
Output:

{"text": "Welcome to", "duration_s": 0.45}
{"text": "in a bottle", "duration_s': 0.44}
```

> `duration = ('end' - 'start') #of the text`

Comment: If you want someone to guide you through something, Stack Overflow isn't the place to look for that. Guiding you through something requires too much back-and-forth interaction for this format; Stack Overflow is more for "ask specific, focused question, get answer, end of interaction".

Comment: So try implementing your pseudocode above and come back to us when you run into *specific* issues.

Comment: welcome to SO. this is a better question than most new users post so don't feel bad. my suggestion for how to edit your question: provide the output your code gives, and provide what you wish the output was. then, since you've already given us the list of dictionaries, people can try code and confirm they've got your desired output. It also takes much less text to explain your desired logic when we have your data and desired output for context.

Comment: Iteration over list with index is extremely un-Pythonic. In Python - in most cases - you iterate **directly** over iterable object

Comment: @MaxPower Thanks, that makes way more sense. will do.

Comment: Can you explain what trouble you're having? It seems like a very straightforward problem to me, but that's from the point of view of someone who already knows how to do all the bits and pieces. Which bit (or piece) are you lost on?

Comment: @AdamSmith Im a novice at programming so excuse my ignorance, i'm not sure on how to break my loop and continue creating a new chunk of text.

Comment: No reason to excuse yourself, you're fine, just helping you to ask an answerable question. I'll take a look when I get home. On mobile atm

Comment: you say you want to output "each consecutive chunk of `case =='success' or duration_s < 10". So why is "story" not part of the output? story has duration seconds  < 10. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @MaxPower it should be "and" not "or", I changed it. Logic is I dont want the duration of the text to be greater than 10s. So even if the next word is 'success' I want it to start a new chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new dictionary without `start` and `end` keys in the middle of the list for the test, does this work for you now? I also changed the duration to be rolling as you clarified.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# add 'duration' var to dicts (makes code in loop clearer)
for dict_ in list_of_dicts:
  try:
    dict_.update({'duration': dict_['end'] - dict_['start']})
  except KeyError:
    dict_['duration'] = 999


# initialize result_dict with keys we'll add to
rolling_duration = 0
result_dict = OrderedDict([('text', ''), ('duration', 0)])

# looping directly through objects as mentioned in comments
for dict_ in list_of_dicts:
  rolling_duration = rolling_duration + dict_['duration']
  #print(dict_['word'], dict_['duration'], rolling_duration)

  if dict_['case'] == 'success' and rolling_duration < 10:
    result_dict['text'] = (result_dict['text'] + " " + dict_['word']).lstrip()
    result_dict['duration'] = round(rolling_duration, 2)

  # print accrued results and reset dict / rolling duration
  else:
    if result_dict['text'] != '':
      print(json.dumps(result_dict))
    result_dict = OrderedDict([('text', ''), ('duration', 0)])
    rolling_duration = 0

# print final json result_dict after exiting loop
print(json.dumps(result_dict))
```

> {"text": "Welcome to", "duration": 0.45}
>
> {"text": "in a Bottle","duration": 0.44}

Comment: This is a great start thank you. It's giving me an error when my list goes over 155 items. It works for the sample set that I provided. 

Also for the duration I dont think I explained that well enough, the duration has to be for the entire chunk of text, less than 10, if the chunk of text exceeds 10 i want to start a new chunk under the same conditions.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/TracyShields/Scribie/Podcast-Data/new_align.py", line 22, in <module>
    dict_.update({'duration': dict_['end'] - dict_['start']})
KeyError: 'end'`


I get that error when my list gets too big.

Comment: your second point is an easy modification. just keep track of a `rolling_duration` variable (not in any dict) and include that in the criteria in the `if` condition.

Comment: the error you're getting is saying that one of the dictionaries in your list of dictionaries does not have an `end` entry. can you confirm that is true? and presuming it is, how would you like to update `duration` when we encounter a dictionary with no `end` field?

Comment: Yeah, it's true. In my sample data I messed up in my sample data. When the `case=='not-found-in-audio'` there is no `end` or `start`. My apologies.

Comment: I'd like to start a new `start` & `end` time from the new chunk so then that duration can be entered. It should skip over `not-found-in-audio` and start a new duration.

Comment: Also if there is `not-found-in-audio` I don't need the `{'text': '', 'duration': 0}` I only want the ones that were successful.

Comment: just updated it once more so result_dict is an OrderedDict. otherwise json output would sometimes have "duration" printed before "text", because regular dictionaries are inherently unordered.

Comment: working great, anyway to get rid of the space at the beginning of each chunk?

Comment: sure. updated with lstrip() - strips leading whitespace from a string

Comment: Update on this, if I wanted to get the start time of the first word and and the end time of the last word of each chunk into a seperate json object how could I do that?

Comment: what have you tried? if you post a new question with something you've tried and how it's not working, and post a link to the new question here, I can answer.

Comment: heads up if you post in the next 2 hours I'll answer before I go to sleep, otherwise I'm off the grid for the night.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solve using a generator that produces the final dictionaries on demand:

```
def split(it):
    it = iter(it)
    acc, duration = [], 0  # defaults
    for item in it:
        if item['case'] != 'success':   # split when there's a non-success
            if acc:
                yield {'text': ' '.join(acc), 'duration': duration}
                acc, duration = [], 0  # reset defaults

        else:
            tmp_duration = item['end'] - item['start']

            if tmp_duration + duration >= 10:  # split when the duration is too long
                if acc:
                    yield {'text': ' '.join(acc), 'duration': duration}
                acc, duration = [item['word']], tmp_duration  # new defaults

            else:
                acc.append(item['word'])
                duration += tmp_duration

    if acc:  # give the remaining items
        yield {'text': ' '.join(acc), 'duration': duration}
```

A simple test gives:

```
>>> list(split(test))
[{'duration': 0.45000000000000007, 'text': 'Welcome to'},
 {'duration': 0.44000000000000017, 'text': 'in a Bottle'}]
```

And this can be easily dumped to a JSON file:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(list(split(test)))
'[{"text": "Welcome to", "duration": 0.45000000000000007}, {"text": "in a Bottle", "duration": 0.44000000000000017}]'
```